# Why are some awards given without any nominations?

Tags: award

For example, in Brit Awards there is a category called Global Icon Award.

The winner in this category is competing against him/herself (Taylor Swift in 2021).

Why are there no nominations in some categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a competitive award, it's essentially an honorary title. Most awards have some version of this category, an award intended to honor someone's entire body of work, and reserved for people who are considered consistent superstars.

Many awards shows, such as the Grammys or the Oscars, call this the "Lifetime Achievement Award" and set it aside for older artists whose best work is probably behind them and who aren't up for contention in other categories. Swift's award was a bit unusual in as much as it was awarded to a still very current artist who was also up for some competitive awards in the same season. For comparison, the first two Global Icon winners were Elton John and David Bowie.